# Appending every excel file in a folder path, pulling sheet 1 and starting on row a2. Pandas/Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, append

I am trying to append every file in a folder path to a master document. Within the file path ALL_YEARS, there are 5 folders (2017 - 2021) that contain different excel files inside each years folder. Sometimes in the one of the years folders can contain another folder, which I will still need to pull the Excel docs from.

To put it more simply, *I need every excel file within ALL_YEARS file.*

All excel xlsx files, only the first sheet of all, and the header starts on row 2 every time.

Code I tried but did not do what I needed

```
print("Using glob.glob()") 
files = glob.glob('files\\path\\ALL_YEARS\\**\\*.xlsx',
               recursive = True) 
for file in files: 
    dfs = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows = 1, sheet_name = 0)

for _, df in dfs.items():
            print(df) 
        
df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.csv')
```

How can I build a loop to get all these files in the path, find sheet 1 and data that starts on row 2, and append to a master csv?

Comment: Have you explored the `xlrd` and `csv` modules?

Comment: I have not. I only looked at glob.glob and trying to and conditions to that. I will update the post for what I had